# ZedGraph - How to display a cursor at an x,y point without using the mouse?

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I am drawing a curve in Zedgraph like this:

```
GraphPane myPane = zgc.GraphPane;
PointPairList list1 = new PointPairList();
for(int i =0; i<10; i++)
    list1.Add(i,i);            
LineItem myCurve = myPane.AddCurve("Title",
          list1, Color.Red, SymbolType.None);        

zgc.AxisChange();
zgc.Refresh();
```

How can I display a cursor (or any other graphic object) at a certain `x`, `y` point on `myCurve` like this:

```
SetCursor(myCurve, list1[3]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing specific point of your curve you can use [`GraphPane.GeneralTransform(...)`](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/M_ZedGraph_GraphPane_GeneralTransform_1.htm) method

So using following code:

```
var myPoint = myCurve[3];
var screenPoint = myPane.GeneralTransform(myPoint.X, myPoint.Y, CoordType.AxisXYScale);
```

would give you coordinates transformed to specific point on screen (in pixels).

Then you need to find some higher-level method (probably in windows forms...) that would move your cursor to that point.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple and more efficient example to create a cross cursor wich is part of the objects collection of the graph so you can operate zooming, printing on it. It add two "LineObj" in the "GraphObjList" collection.
The code : Put a cursor at the 10th point of the first curve

```
    Dim myPane As GraphPane = zg1.GraphPane    
    Dim myPoint As PointPair = myPane.CurveList.Item(0).Points(10)
    Dim CurseurV1 As New LineObj(Color.Blue, myPoint.X,myPane.YAxis.Scale.Min, myPoint.X, myPane.YAxis.Scale.Max)

    CurseurV1.Line.Width = 0.5
    myPane.GraphObjList.Add(CurseurV1)

    Dim CurseurH1 As New LineObj(Color.Blue, myPane.XAxis.Scale.Min,myPoint.Y, myPane.XAxis.Scale.Max, myPoint.Y)
    CurseurH1.Line.Width = 1
    myPane.GraphObjList.Add(CurseurH1)
```

It's done : you'd have a blue "cross" cursor on your graphe using ZedGraph.dll Version 5.1.2.878.